# Should I inherit a nested class within a derived class in c++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, nested-class

Could (**Edit: Should**) I do something like this?

**Edit:**

I'll try asking about an example that may be better suited to this inheritence scheme. Note this isn't a working class, just for the concept.

```
template<typename T>
class Tree {
protected:
    class Node {
       Node* _parent;
       T _data
    };
};

template<typename T>
class BinaryTree: public Tree {
private:
    class BinaryNode: public Tree<T>::Node {
        Node *_left, *_right;
    };
};
```

Comment: try it? Just make the Iterator public, now it's private. Also it might need to be List::Iterator.

Comment: You can always try... compilers don't bite. And usually won't delete your home files, when you mess up.

Comment: I'll edit this a bit...

Comment: @Dori please add semicolons to the close braces of your `class`es.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way of constructing parallel class hierarchies is not uncommon. However, it is more common to hide the nested derived class as an implementation detail that should be encapsulated, i.e. the `BiIterator` in your example would be in the `private:` section.

However, `Iterator` is not a good example because of object slicing: even if `BiIterator` remains public, this seemingly innocent code is incorrect:

```
BidirectionalList biList;
// This would slice off BiIterator's functionality
Iterator iter(biList.get_iterator());
while (iter.has_next()) {
    ...
}
```

A better example would be if the base class member function took a reference or a pointer to an object of a nested class defined in the base, and a derived class would pass its derived nested class for it:

```
class Task {
public:
    class Worker {
        public virtual void work()=0;
    }
    void run(Worker& w);
};
class SpecialTask : public Task {
private:
    class SpecialWorker : public Worker {
        public virtual void work() {
            ...
        }
    };
public:
    void do_something() {
        SpecialWorker w;
        run(w); // Passes SpecialWorker to run() of base class
    }
};
```

Comment: In your example of incorrect code: why would I do that? If I have a bidirectional list, I would use a `BiIterator`, not an `Iterator`, so no slicing would occur...?

Comment: @Dori That's a good question: you would do that if you do not want any additional functionality from your `BiIterator`, only the functionality from the `Iterator`. This is called "programming to interface".

Comment: So when would I want to program to interface without slicing? When would I *not* want to slice the `BiIterator` if I do *not* want the added functionality?

Comment: @Dori It is generally a good idea to program to interface whenever you can: accept the class with the minimal functionality that you need, even though you know a subclass exists. C++ makes this harder, because you need to use a reference or a pointer for that to avoid slicing.

Comment: Thanks - I updated my example to field inheritence, not necessarily method inheritence. Could you take a look?

Comment: @Dori Your new example of a private nested class inherits implementation from a protected nested class is very common.

Comment: I kind of feel like I was looking for someone to say 'go ahead', so thanks :) but maybe @Jonathan Mee will prove me wrong after all...

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing illegal about what you're doing so you **could** do it.

As far as **should** you, that's less clear cut.

But for this example I do think the answer is clear. When implementing C++ containers they decided to implement `iterator` separately from all their container classes. Benefiting from their wisdom wouldn't be a bad choice in this case.

**EDIT:**

For a container structure your contained object type should be templatized. For my proof I'd again reference C++ container design.

But here I think it's much more clear cut. If you write an excellent `Tree` or `BinaryTree` `class` that's templatized, you could use that over and over in all the code you write for the rest of your life. Why not take advantage of that?

(Just a word of caution you might be reinventing the wheel here. Have a look at this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/make_heap/)

Comment: Updated my example, could you take a look?

Comment: Isn't it templatized? The `Node` has a `T` in it, as does (by nested inheritence) the `BinaryNode`. Also, this is Uni homework so yes, I'm reinventing the wheel :)

Comment: @Dori Yes, but I was suggesting a single container, with a collection of nodes the iteration gets sketchy.

Comment: Could you elaborate? What iteration? I want a base `Tree` class so I can inherit and create a `BinaryTree` and a `TrinaryTree` and such. They each have very different 'iteration' methods, but they are all `Tree`s, and each node has data and a parent. What do you mean by 'a collection of nodes'?

Comment: @Dori This is a lot to explain in comment. Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/647012/Fast-Binary-Search-Trees-BST-using-Arrays) out. Can you see how under this implementation I have the flexibility to use `operator[]` to index into an exact "Node". I can also iterate across a level of a tree rather than just moving up and down. Of course it's fair to note that tree setup costs can be higher.